# Embedding a Java Applet

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I'm trying to get a Java Applet to display on a webpage. The applet runs in Eclipse, but does nothing on the webpage.
For reference here is the applet (no, it's not complete):

```
package TestProg.webClient;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class UserLogin extends Applet {
    String accountId = "";

    public void init() {
        TextField username = new TextField(10);
        TextField password = new TextField(10);
        Button login = new Button("   Log In   ");
        add(username);
        add(password);
        add(login);
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
  <center>
    <div id="title"><h1>UserLogin</h1></div>
  </center>
  <applet code="sp.jar" width="400" height="100" alt="This isn't working"></applet>
</body>
```

I've also tried embedding with `<object>` and `<embed>`, have tried with both Chrome and Firefox on a Linux machine, and for some reason took the .class file out of the .jar and tried that. 
Absolutely nothing displays on the webpage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was, and there seems to be a severe lacking of this knowledge out there....

The HTML tag *should* look like this...

`<applet code=NameOfPackage.NameOfApplet archive=NameOfApplet.jar width=300 height=300>`

Thanks to all who helped...

Answer (score 1):

Can the code attributte be a .jar ? Everything in the right directory?

Try something like this:

```
<applet code=NameOfApplet.class name=NameOfApplet archive=NameOfApplet.jar
    width=300 height=300>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work, per se, but if I switched to another tab and back, the part of the webpage that was where the applet should be remained on this page. It's getting closer.

Comment: Well spotted.  Note that the code attribute should be the fully qualified class name, so instead of `NameOfApplet.class`, just `NameOfApplet`.  Irritatingly, most of Sun (now Oracle) old examples add the extension, which is tolerated, rather than correct.

Comment: I removed the .class and .jar... had the same problem. Ah well, I can do this in PHP, I just really wanted to do it in java.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Jpanel before you add your button and text box.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // Used to center the panel
    content.add(panel);
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not change anything. It works when I run it in eclipse, but does not work in a browser.

Comment: I discovered what the problem was, and there seems to be a lacking of this information (at least from where I saw).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the pluging for java on yout browser ?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html

Comment: Yes. I can view other applets in Firefox with no problem, but it seems to be hit or miss with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it on the site, you could wrap it using http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ and providing a link to download the executable you made. Perhaps wrap it as an exe than modify the java code to submit values to the server. Then, tell the user to reload the page if the server responds that it received the information. Sorry, it is a clumsy workaround- but it might work.

Comment: Thanks, but it really should be on the website. I think I'm just going  to have to do this with PHP instead, which I really don't want to.

Comment: php is not so bad... :P
http://www.w3schools.com/php/
< Is always useful, no matter how good you are at it.