# I compiled my entire program and there is no errors, but nothing shows when I run it

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point, main-method

I think this is weird because when I ran it before on Eclipse, this program worked. However, when I try to run it using 'java PacMan', then nothing shows up. I think it is because I am missing a main method, but I'm not sure how to integrate that into my program without screwing everything up.

```
/*
   PacMan.java
   This is a lame replica of the game PacMan. The PacMan
   starts out on a random location on the board with
   6 ghosts & cheese. It must try to eat the cheese without
   getting eaten by the ghosts. The ghosts only move around
   when PacMan does. All characters on the board can only move
   around when PacMan does and can only move up, down, left,
   and right; diagonal movement isn't allowed. When PacMan eats
   all the cheese, the words 'YOU WIN! :)' will be displayed across
   the board; if you lose, 'YOU LOST! :(' will be shown.
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PacMan extends JApplet implements KeyListener
{
    private int chez, ghosts;
    private int currentx, currenty, direction, a;
    private int [][] grid;
    private int [] alienx, alieny;
    private DrawingArea canvas;
    private boolean lost;

  public void init()
  {
      setSize(500, 560);
      generateBoard();
      canvas = new DrawingArea(); // drawing area
      getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
      getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
      canvas.addKeyListener(this);
      canvas.requestFocus();
  }
  public void generateBoard()
  {
      lost = false;
      chez = ghosts = currentx = currenty = 0;
      grid = new int[10][10]; // sets 2D array size
      alienx = new int[6];
      alieny = new int[6];
      do
      {
          currentx = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          currenty = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          if(grid[currentx][currenty] == 0 && chez < 6)
          {
              grid[currentx][currenty] = 1; // placement holder because 0 won't be read in
              chez++; // '1' is the cheese
          }
          if(grid[currentx][currenty] == 0 && ghosts < 6)
          {
              grid[currentx][currenty] = 2; // placement holder because 0 won't be read in
              alienx[ghosts] = currentx;
              alieny[ghosts] = currenty;
              ghosts++; // '2' is the ghosts
          }
      }
      while(chez < 6 || ghosts < 6);
      do  // this makes sure PacMan never respawns on a ghost or cheese
      {
          currentx = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          currenty = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      }
      while(grid[currentx][currenty] != 0);
      grid[currentx][currenty] = 3; // this is PacMan
      direction = 0;
  }
  public void moveGhosts(int a)
  {
      int oldx = alienx[a], oldy = alieny[a]; // coordinates of the aliens
      grid[oldx][oldy] = 0; // erases original spacing for monster/alien
      int stuff; // used for random statement
      boolean done = true;
      stuff = (int)(Math.random() * 8 + 1); // amount of random moves XD
      do
      {
         switch(stuff)
         {
            case 1: alienx[a]++; break; // down
            case 2: alienx[a]--; break; // up
            case 3: alieny[a]++; break; // right
            case 4: alieny[a]--; break; // left
            case 5: alienx[a]++; alieny[a]--; break; // down, left
            case 6: alienx[a]++; alieny[a]++; break; // down, right
            case 7: alienx[a]--; alieny[a]--; break; // up, left
            case 8: alienx[a]--; alieny[a]++; break; // up, right
         }
         if(alieny[a] == 10)
            alieny[a] = 0;
         if(alieny[a] == -1)
            alieny[a] = 9;
         if(alienx[a] == 10)
            alienx[a] = 0;
         if(alienx[a] == -1)
            alienx[a] = 9;
         if(grid[alienx[a]][alieny[a]] == 0 || grid[currentx][currenty] == 3)
            done = true; // only runs when ghost is on empty space or eats PacMan
         else
            done = false; // makes sure ghost never eats cheese
         for(int b = 0; b < 6; b++)
            if(alienx[b] == alienx[a] && alieny[b] == alieny[a] && b != a)
               done = false; // prevents ghosts from overlaping each other
         if (!done)
         {
            oldx = alienx[a];
            oldy = alieny[a];
         }
       } while (!done);
       grid[alienx[a]][alieny[a]] = 2;
  }
  class DrawingArea extends JPanel
  {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         displayBoard(g);
         this.requestFocus();
      }
      public void displayBoard(Graphics g)
      {
          g.setColor(Color.gray);
          g.fillRect(116, 464, 270, 50); // gray background for board
          g.fillRect(30, 10, 445, 445); // gray background for 'cheese remaining'
          g.setColor(Color.yellow);
          g.drawRect(116, 464, 270, 50); // outlines 'cheese remaining' box
          if(grid[currentx][currenty] == 1) // makes cheese disappear when PacMan eats it
          {
             grid[currentx][currenty] = 0;
             chez--;
          }
          if(grid[currentx][currenty] == 2) // makes PacMan disappear when he hits a ghost
           lost = true;
          Font progress = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25);
             g.setFont(progress);
          if(!lost && chez > 0)
             g.drawString("Cheese Remaining:"+ chez, 130, 500); // shows # of cheese left
          else if(lost == true)
             g.drawString("YOU LOST! :(", 175, 500);
          else if(chez == 0)
             g.drawString("YOU WON! :)", 175, 500);
          g.setColor(Color.white);
          for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
             for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++)
             {
                 g.setColor(Color.white);
                 g.fillRect(30 + col * 45, 10 + row * 45, 40, 40); // prints grid
                 g.setColor(Color.blue); // primitive PacMan
                 if(!lost)
                     g.fillArc(30 + currentx * 45, 10 + currenty * 45, 40, 40, direction + 30, 300);
                 if(grid[col][row] == 1) // prints out cheese randomly if array encounters invisible '1'
                 {
                                                                                    // while scanning
                     g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                     g.fillRect(33 + col * 45, 13 + row * 45, 33, 33); // blocks of cheese
                 }
                 if(grid[col][row] == 2) // prints out ghosts randomly if array encounters invisible '2'
                 {
                                                                                        // while scanning
                     g.setColor(Color.red);
                     g.fillOval(30 + col * 45, 10 + row * 45, 40, 40); // ghosts' body
                     g.setColor(Color.black);
                     g.fillOval(38 + col * 45, 20 + row * 45, 8, 8); // left eye
                     g.fillOval(53 + col * 45, 20 + row * 45, 8, 8); // right eye
                     g.drawLine(38 + col * 45, 37 + row * 45, 61 + col * 45, 37 + row * 45); // mouth
                 }
             }
       }
  }
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
  {
      int value = evt.getKeyCode();
      if(!lost && chez > 0)
      switch(value)
      {
       case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
          {
           currentx--;   // PacMan moves left
              if(currentx == -1) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
               currentx = 9;
              direction = 180; //faces left
              for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
              moveGhosts(a);
          } break;
       case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
          {
              currentx++;   // PacMan moves right
              if(currentx == 10) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
               currentx = 0;
              direction = 0; //faces right
              for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
              moveGhosts(a);
          } break;
          case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
          {
              currenty--;   // PacMan moves up
              if(currenty == -1) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
               currenty = 9;
              direction = 90; //faces up
              for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
              moveGhosts(a);
          } break;
          case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
          {
              currenty++;   // PacMan moves down
              if(currenty == 10) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
               currenty = 0;
              direction = 270; //faces down
              for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
              moveGhosts(a);
          } break;
     }
     if(value == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
     generateBoard(); // call on method to regenerate board
     canvas.repaint(); // repaints the board
  }
  class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
  {
      private JButton left, right, up, down, reset;
      public ButtonPanel() // displays available buttons
      {
              left = new JButton("LEFT");
           left.addActionListener(this);
           this.add(left);
          right = new JButton("RIGHT");
           right.addActionListener(this);
           this.add(right);
          up = new JButton("UP");
           up.addActionListener(this);
               this.add(up);
          down = new JButton("DOWN");
           down.addActionListener(this);
           this.add(down);
          reset = new JButton("RESET");
           reset.addActionListener(this);
           this.add(reset);
     }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
     {
         String command = evt.getActionCommand();
         if(!lost && chez > 0)
         {
                 if(command.equals("LEFT"))
             {
                 currentx--;   // PacMan moves left
                 if(currentx == -1) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
                 currentx = 9;
                 direction = 180; //faces left
                 for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
                 moveGhosts(a);
             }
             else if(command.equals("RIGHT"))
             {
                      currentx++;   // PacMan moves right
                 if(currentx == 10) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
                 currentx = 0;
                 direction = 0; //faces right
                 for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
                 moveGhosts(a);
             }
             else if(command.equals("UP"))
             {
                      currenty--;   // PacMan moves up
                 if(currenty == -1) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
                 currenty = 9;
                 direction = 90; //faces up
                 for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
                 moveGhosts(a);
             }
             else if(command.equals("DOWN"))
             {
                      currenty++;   // PacMan moves down
                 if(currenty == 10) // makes sure the PacMan can 'loop' around through 'portals'
                 currenty = 0;
                 direction = 270; //faces down
                 for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
                 moveGhosts(a);
             }
         }
        if(command.equals("RESET"))
        generateBoard(); // call on method to regenerate board
        canvas.repaint(); // repaints the board
       }
  }
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {}
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {}
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {}
}
```

Comment: You have to embed your application in a webpage, it's an applet, you don't run it with `java yourapp`

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: and is there anyway to just put a main method into the program to make it work?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590033/embedding-a-java-applet

Comment: so to embed, i would have to use an html file to call upon the PacMan class, to make it work on a webpage

Comment: @BackSlash you do not have to put it within a browser.  You can actually run it from within another java application.  If you look at my post it has a link to example code on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like they said in the comments because it is an applet you can not treat it as a regular java application.  However, you can embed it into a browser or you can use the java tool `appletviewer` to run it without a browser.  In your command line type in the following:

appletviewer [ options ] myApplet.html

Just put a `myApplet.html` in the folder:

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Pac Man Applet</Title>
</Head>

<Body>
<Applet Code="MyApplet.class" width=200 Height=100>
</Applet>
</Body>
</Html>
```

The additional option is to create a stub application that will allow you to run an applet within a java application:  [Here is link to example.](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0102/lazar/index.html)  The example code is at bottom.

Comment: how would I use appletviewer? is it kind of like if I ran it in eclipse, it would just pop out a new little window without me having to embed the applet in some HTML code?

Comment: I put the name of my class that I want to run (PacMan.class) in there, and I saved an html file. However, when I type the appletviewer [options] myApplet.html, I get this: I/O exception while reading: (my desktop info down to my folder)[options] (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer the `.html` file has to be in the same folder as the applet and you have to navigate to that folder before you can run the command.

Comment: ok i got it to work by typing appletviewer PacMan.class myApplet.html THANKS! :)

Comment: it was already in the same file before I think I was just typing something wrong (like I think I actually typed options when you are actually just suppose to run the applet.class file :P)